# Creating a hidden wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

My question might sound stupid but is there any way where I can create a WP plugin which when placed in Plugins folder does not appear in WP Admin Console and WP Admins/Users can't deactivate it from UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're searching is called "must-use plugin" or "mu-plugin". An mu-plugin is a plugin that is automatically activated when you install it, and it cannot be deactivated.

Basically, an mu-plugin is like a normal plugin. The only difference is that you will install it in `wp-content/mu-plugins` instead of `wp-content/plugins`. I wrote [a complete guide to mu-plugins](http://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-mu-plugins/) on SitePoint if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks. Will a mu-plugin be visible in list of installed plugins in WP Admin Panel?

Comment: Yes, in a new "must-use" tab. However, they are just listed to know they exist, we can't deactivate them from here. If you want to hide them, I just found a way to do this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hide-mu-plugins-list?replies=2